# NameError: name 'python' is not defined when importing part of tensorflow's deeplab module

Tags: tensorflow

Thanks to [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15741), I realise that I shouldn't try to reload tensorflow, because I get this error:

```
 del python
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

when I do

```
import tensorflow
from deeplab import common
```

In case it's relevant, `import deeplab` works fine.

I saw elsewhere that it's probably the IPython session in spyder that is keeping a tensorflow session open. So I closed spyder - but launching python in the shell gave me the same issue. `ps -ef | grep -E 'py|tensorflow|tensorboard|tf'` came up empty. What could still be hanging around and causing tensorflow to try a reload, rather than a fresh load?

I understand that the issue around reloading tensorflow will not be resolved. How do I make sure that I have cleared everything from my previous runs so that it will be a fresh load rather than a reload?

Edit: even after restarting the computer I get the same error. Even if the first thing I do is open a python console and type `from deeplab import common`. That means the original title to my question is probably wrong, so I have changed it.

Comment: I had a similar issue in Linux. I exit from the python shell and entering the shell again resolved my issue.